# Simulate data with specified signal to noise ratio for a given sigma

Tags: time-series, simulation

Imagine I have a series $y$ that has a signal and a noise component $y=S+N$. How can I generate $y$ from $S$ and $N$ so that $y$ is 80% signal, 20% noise, and has a given standard deviation?

```
# Set desired parameters
signal_length <- 100

sigmaY <- 10

# Generate signal and noise
signal <- rnorm(signal_length, mean = 0, sd = sigmaY)
noise <- rnorm(signal_length, mean = 0, sd = sigmaY)

# Define weights for signal and noise
signal_weight <- 0.8
noise_weight <- 0.2

# Combine with weights
y <- signal_weight * signal + noise_weight * noise

# ~8
sd(y)
```

I'd like to have the sd of `y` be `sigmaY`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Signal" and "noise" can be interpreted in a few ways.  Let me give you my two cents.

Consider a regression of $y_i = \alpha x + \beta + \epsilon_i$.  In this context, variation in the outcome due to $x$ is considered "signal" while unexplained variation (i.e. $\epsilon$) is often referred to as "noise".  A term that involves both "signal" and "noise" is $R^2$ (the coefficient of variation), and it is fairly simple to generate a regression problem for a given signal and noise.

Let's analyze this for a single varibale regression.  Let's make the assumption that the predictor is normally distributed and that it has variance $\tau^2$.

Now, assume $y\vert x \sim N(\alpha x + \beta, \sigma^2)$.  The marginal distribution of $y$ is then $y \sim N(\alpha \mu + \beta, \sigma^2 + \alpha^2\tau^2)$ meaning that the the exact value for $R^2$ would be

$$R^2 = 1 - \dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + \alpha^2\tau^2} = 1 - \dfrac{1}{1  + \left(\dfrac{\alpha \tau}{\sigma}\right)^2} \>.$$

We can always standardize our predictor to have unit variance, so the quantity we really care about is $\alpha/\sigma$.  I can rearrange the formula for $R^2$ to give me $\alpha = \alpha(\sigma)$ and since we really only care about the ratio of $\alpha$ and $\sigma$ I'll assume $\sigma=1$ and modulate $\alpha$.  Now, I can generate a regression problem which has true $R^2$ whatever I want it to be.  Here is some code to do that.

```r
set.seed(0)
make_regression <- function(n, alpha, sigma){
  
  x <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
  y <- alpha * x + rnorm(n, 0, sigma)
  
  data.frame(x, y)
}

R2 <- 0.8
sigma <- 1
alpha <- sigma * sqrt(1/(1-R2) -1)

d <- make_regression(10000, alpha, sigma)

fit <- lm(y~x, data=d)

summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ x, data = d)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -3.8080 -0.6721  0.0090  0.6842  3.3531 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) -0.004689   0.009969   -0.47    0.638    
#> x            2.006897   0.010006  200.56   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.9968 on 9998 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.8009, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8009 
#> F-statistic: 4.022e+04 on 1 and 9998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note that the $R^2$ is 0.8 (up to sampling variation) as desired.  The only thing here is that the denominator of $R^2$ is the *total* variation (that is signal plus noise), so you have to do a little extra math to convert your desired signal to noise ratio to the appropriate $R^2$.

Comment: Great answer. @user111024 did ask for 80% signal and 20% noise, so I think your choice of value for $R^2$ is right.

Comment: @ZKA not quite. R squared measures noise to total variation in y (I.e noise to signal plus noise). Need a little extra algebra to turn signal:noise to the right r squared, but I think OP can handle that.

Comment: What am I misunderstanding here? You're saying $R^2 = \frac{S}{S+N}$ so $R^2 = 0.8 = \frac{0.8}{0.8+0.2}$ means 80% signal, 20% noise, and a signal-to-noise-ratio of 4:1. No?

Comment: @ZKA oh haha, I guess that’s just a happy accident in my part then! I didn’t plan that